# Round 2 digit after decimal point after zero in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume I have a float:

```
x = 0.0005953829144211724
```

I have to round it after the decimal to:

```
x = 0.00059
```

Similarly, if

```
x = 0.00000046605219739046376
```

then the result should be

```
x = 0.00000046
```

Is there any inbuild function in python to do this?

Comment: Which version of Python are you actually asking about?

Comment: @ScottHunter I am referring to Python3.8

Comment: 0.00000046605219739046376 doesn't *round* to 0.00000046.  Similarly, 0.0005953829144211724 doesn't *round* to 0.00059.

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with `python-2.7`?

Comment: @ScottHunter I edited that. I believe function would remail the same moreover.

Comment: On what basis do you hold any belief about a function you do not know exists?

Comment: There is no built-in function which would do this weird kind of transformation which vaguely resembles rounding. But you can write our own.

Comment: You should only round when you output a number. Rounding for calculations can lead to unexpected results due to the nature of floating point numbers.

Comment: What about a number such as 1234.0, what should be the solution? What if it were 1.0256?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested format with Decimal.  The first format does the rounding using the "g" specifier.  The second one prints all the digits, without scientific notation, using the decimal value of the rounded string:

```
from decimal import Decimal

x = 0.0005953829144211724
print(f"{Decimal(f'{x:.2g}'):f}") # 0.0006
print(f"{Decimal(f'{x:.3g}'):f}") # 0.000595
print(f"{Decimal(f'{x:.4g}'):f}") # 0.0005954

x = 0.00000046605219739046376
print(f"{Decimal(f'{x:.2g}'):f}") # 0.00000047
print(f"{Decimal(f'{x:.3g}'):f}") # 0.000000466
print(f"{Decimal(f'{x:.4g}'):f}") # 0.0000004661
```

*Note that this DOES round the value to the specified precision, contrary to your examples which truncate the mantissa instead of rounding it*

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the other answer, if you want a certain number of significant digits, you should format the number in scientific notation. If, however, you want those significant digits in the "normal" format, you might either convert that scientific notation back to float (thus "forgetting" all the "insignificant" digits) and *then* back to string and `rstrip` all excess zeros, or maybe use a regular expression:

```
>>> x = 0.00000046605219739046376
>>> f'{float(f"{x:.2g}"):.20f}'.rstrip("0")
'0.00000047'
>>> re.match(r"0\.0*[^0]{2}", f"{x:.20f}").group()
'0.00000046'
```

Note: i) The `.20f` here means "print in normal decimal format with 20 places after the decimal", where the 20 is kind of arbitrary. ii) The regex will not round but just trim the number.

Comment: (+1) I was going to suggest this, the only difference is that I would add `\d+` before the dot in case he wants to process something like `123.00000123`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something close with the `g` specifier in an f-string:

```
x = 0.00000046605219739046376
print(f'{x:.2g}')
```

This will print the result in "scientific notation"

```
4.7e-07
```

Similarly:

```
x = 0.0005953829144211724
print(f'{x:.2g}')
```

results in

```
0.0006
```

since it rounds up.